# Scale sprite error

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I'm working on an iPhone app in objective-c also using cocos2d for graphics.  I have a large sprite and I have done research on how to scale the sprite and my code looks like this...

```
//Set up sprite
    // Use batch node. Faster
    CCSpriteBatchNode *parent = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"egg.png" capacity:100];
    eggTexture_ = [parent texture];

    [eggTexture_ setScaleX: 10/eggTexture_.contentSize.width];
    [eggTexture_ setScaleY: 10/eggTexture_.contentSize.height];
```

And it compiles fine! Then I get a run time error "SIGABRT".  I can't find the problem.  It's probably something amature.  Looking back there are "warnings" after those last to lines that reads "CCTexture2d may not respond to setScaleX".  Any help is much appreciated :) thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the class CCTexture2D does not respond to setScaleX and setScaleY. The object picked by the statement [parent texture] is a texture, thus you must be getting an error message similar to this

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CCTexture2D setScaleX:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5e14c70'

I am not certain why you would want to scale the texture, i suspect you would rather scale a CCSprite, and place that in your scene. like :

```
CCSprite *eggSprite_ = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:[parent texture]];
[eggSprite_ setScaleX: 10/eggSprite_.contentSize.width];
```

etc ...

Comment: Ok now that I changed the CCTexture2d to CCSprite... it no longer works later in the code when I need to use the sprite in box2d how do I turn the CCSprite to a PhysicsSprite

Comment: ohh ... sorry, your purpose was not clear in the question. I have no practical knowledge of box2D nor its API. Does 'PhysicsSprite' have an init (creator) with a cocos2d Sprite, or even derives from CCSprite ? that is as far as i would venture to guess :).